# Storing log file in AWS S3 from Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, log4j

I am building a Spring-boot application where in all the logging is stored in a specified path in log4j.properties.

I am hosting this application on AWS Beanstalk.

Once I host the application on the AWS, the specified path for the log file will become invalid.

How can I resolve this issue where in the log file should also get stored in a different path in cloud, say Amazon S3, but not on server as the log file takes considerable amount of size.

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/my_log.log
```

How can I change the above line to store the "my_log.log" in AWS S3?

Comment: Did you try s3://path/to/bucket ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that Prasoon, with no luck.

Comment: I think only paths relative to the machine you are in would work for the log files. What you can do is write a small utility that copies the logs to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi Santhosh, Did you able to make it work. If so could you share how you did it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;


@Autowired
    private AmazonS3 s3Client;
@Scheduled(cron = "0 5 1 * * *")
public void moveLogsFromEC2ToS3() {
    try {
        File logsDir = new File(env.getProperty("AWS_EC2_LOG_PATH"));
        for (File logFile : logsDir.listFiles()) {
            String fileName = logFile.getName();
            if (fileName.endsWith(".log")) {
                s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(env.getProperty("AWS_S3_LOGS_BUCKET_NAME"), fileName, logFile));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in moving log files! : {}", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although user has mentioned log4j, in case someone is using logback, they could use this library.
https://github.com/link-nv/logback-s3-rolling-policy

```
logback-s3-rolling-policy automatically uploads rolled log files to S3.

There are 2 rolling policies which can be used:

- S3FixedWindowRollingPolicy
- S3TimeBasedRollingPolicy
```

User would need to use these Rolling policies in their `RollingFileAppender` configuraiton

Example:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>logs/myapp.log</file>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>[%d] %-8relative %22c{0} [%-5level] %msg%xEx{3}%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.S3FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>logs/myapp.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    <awsAccessKey>ACCESS_KEY</awsAccessKey>
    <awsSecretKey>SECRET_KEY</awsSecretKey>
    <s3BucketName>myapp-logging</s3BucketName>
    <s3FolderName>logs/%d{yyyy/MM/dd}</s3FolderName>
    <rolloverOnExit>true</rolloverOnExit>
    <shutdownHookType>SERVLET_CONTEXT</shutdownHookType>
    <prefixTimestamp>true</prefixTimestamp>
    <prefixIdentifier>true</prefixIdentifier>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
  </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Log file should also get stored in a different path in cloud, say Amazon S3.

I am sure that you cannot log your info directly to S3. It is a costlier process. First you have to log in EC2 instance and then you have to sync to sync your log you can use LogRotate.

To Store your log in S3 refer [logrotate apache logs to amazon S3](https://lustforge.com/2012/07/15/logrotate-apache-logs-to-amazon-s3/).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by storing the log files in a Amazon EC2 location where your web server is installed.
I was storing in Amazon EC2 instance as my web server was hosted there. You can choose our own location.
And then wrote a cron job inside my Spring boot application itself to copy these files from Amazon EC2 to Amazon S3 once in every 24 hours.

Comment: Same issue being faced in my case as well, logs are consuming considerable amount of disk space. So, did you mean every 24 hrs you do a mv operation from EC2 to S3 or a cp operation from EC2 to S3 followed by rm the logs from EC2 ?

Comment: Posted the answer below. You can follow the same.