Could not create component [rollingPolicy] of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.S3FixedWindowRollingPolicy]
I have an app running a Java Spring Boot backend. I'm trying to switch from storing logs locally to pushing them to an Amazon S3 bucket. Here is my old appender for reference. This was working as intended.
<!-- AdminServer Log Appender -->
    <appender name="AdminServer" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}/adminServer.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/adminServer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>2000</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

The only thing  changed was my rolling policy which is now
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.S3FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/adminServer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <awsAccessKey>ACCESS_KEY</awsAccessKey>
            <awsSecretKey>SECRET_KEY</awsSecretKey>
            <s3BucketName>myapp-logging</s3BucketName>
            <s3FolderName>logs/%d{yyyy/MM/dd}</s3FolderName>
            <rolloverOnExit>true</rolloverOnExit>
            <shutdownHookType>SERVLET_CONTEXT</shutdownHookType>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>2000</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

I get the error from the title saying that it could not find the class.
I found this answer to another question regarding rolling logs in to an S3 bucket and my configuration looks like theirs.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71587015/23485744
I tried looking for a maven dependency related to the S3FixedWindowRollingPolicy but it seems as though it is part of the logback core. here are the dependencies I have related to logging
        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


I also tried looking through the GitHub readme located here https://github.com/link-nv/logback-s3-rolling-policy/blob/master/README.md but I wasn't able to find the answer to the ClassNotFoundException.
